# How do I solve congruences with two variables and distinct moduli?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, congruences

I'm interested in solving congruences such as $$x \equiv 4 \bmod{13}\\ y \equiv 7 \bmod{19}\\x \equiv y \bmod{6}$$In other words, linear congruences across two variables with distinct, coprime moduli. Notice that in this problem, two of the congruences involve only a single variable. I'd like a fast and simple way to find solutions. Any ideas?

I did stumble across this paper on a Multivariable version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5114.pdf), which might be helpful. I'm looking for something very simple which I can implement easily in real code.

Comment: x=13a+4, y = 19b+7 and we require that 13a-19b is congruent to 3 mod 6, equivalently a-b congruent to 3 mod 6. So take a=b+3+6k where b, k are arbitrary and this should give you your solutions

Comment: I think there is no general easy way. Your concrete problem can be solved by brute force : Take the $6$ pairs $(0/0)$ to $(5/5)$ modulo $6$ and for each apply the chinese remainder theorem for $x$ and $y$ seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Let moduli be $m_1, \dots, m_k$. Compute $M=\mathrm{lcm}(m_1, \dots, m_k)$ and multiply the $i$-th congruence by $M/m_i$ to get the system of linear equations over the ring of integers modulo $M$.

This way your example
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv 4\pmod{13}\\
y\equiv 7\pmod{19}\\
x\equiv y\pmod{6}
\end{cases}$$
is turned into
$$\begin{cases}
114x\equiv 456\pmod{1482}\\
78y\equiv 546\pmod{1482}\\
247x\equiv 247y\pmod{1482}
\end{cases}$$
where all congruences are modulo $1482$.